# Flask mail Python : Add break line in the message body

Tags: python, email, flask-mail

Having trouble with the syntax to add break line to the message body using Flask Mail Python.

Tried 
 tags but wouldn't work.

```
msg = Message('Title', sender = 'sender@gmail.com', recipients = ['receiver@gmail.com'] )
msg.body = "Hi,<br> Paragraph1 <br> Thank you."
mail.send(msg)
```

My desired result for the message body would look like this.

Hi,

Paragraph xxxxxxxxxxxxx

Thank you.

Comment: `"Hi,\r\n<br> Paragraph1 \r\n<br> Thank you."` for text you can use `\r\n`

Comment: Bear Brown is right.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
msg.body = "Hi,\r\n Paragraph1 \r\n Thank you."
```

Thanks to @Bear Brown and @Xavien Johnson

Comment: glad to help you, don't forget to accept your answer for other who will search the same issue